# How to organise data in java / testng test for rest APIs

Tags: java, rest, testng, data-driven-tests

Just started working at a new place where I need to test rest calls (GETs for now) with different path / query parameters that I need to pass based on the scenario. Some of these parameters may be in a database, but I cannot use that, since only specific combinations are valid. So data has to reside in the test project. In a previous company, we used data providers and spreadsheets. But there is too much data here and spreadsheets don't version well. Any ideas on how I can tackle the problem? Any general/specific help will be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I'd suggest creating builders that would prepare data dynamically (possibly randomized), something like this:

```
Dog dog = Dog.random();
```

The method has to create a valid but random dog, e.g.

```
public static Dog random() {
    Dog dog = new Dog();
    dog.setName(english(10));
    if(    bool()    ) dog.setOwner(Owner.random());//50% chance to have owner
    if(dog.hasOwner()) dog.setAddress(Address.random());
    return dog;
}
```

Want to test something specific in one particular test? You can override random values with something more concrete:

```
Dog dog = Dog.createDogOnLeash();
dog.setAddress(null);
```

This way you may test a lot of combinations with time. The more tests you write the more combinations are tested per each run. See [this post](http://qala.io/blog/test-data-management.html) for additional info.

The data doesn't have to be randomized, but it helps to simplify things. Otherwise you'd be forced to put a lot of hardcoded data in tests (or even worse - in separate files) which would be harder to maintain.

Comment: This is very interesting... Will leave the question open for more suggestion, but will explore the above in the mean time.